# How to use POSTMAN to send data and files to the following website

Tags: rest, post, postman

I have an interview assignment where I need to submit details and resume to the following website:
http://sr-recruit.herokuapp.com

I am using POSTMAN to submit that. When I tried to give a GET call to the link above I get the following output in the body as below:

```
{
  "message": "POST to /resumes with 'name', 'email', 'about' (255 max) and 'file' (attachment) instead."
}
```

Can I know how to post my data with all the keys above together with my resume by uploading it in the postman. I was not able to view any form-data in the body to upload the file and when I try to use the POST method I get the following error.

```
{
  "message": "These parameters are required: 'name', 'email', 'about' (255 max) and 'file' (attachment)"
}
```

[image]

Can anyone please guide me If I am doing the correct way or If I am doing it wrong and how to send my data to this web ? If the way I am trying to do is correct can I know how I can upload my resume into that "file" key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're doing a `POST` and not a `GET`, and that it's to the /resumes endpoint, and that you also select a file:

[image]

Comment: That was handy!!